# Difference between IPI_CALL_FUNC and IPI_IRQ_WORK

Tags: linux, arm, interrupt, arm64

On ARM64 Linux I can use both IPI's to trigger the execution of certain functions on another processor. If I understood it correctly the IPI_CALL_FUNC is generic and I can invoke arbitrary functions with it, while the IPI_IRQ_WORK is used to forward IRQ handling to other processors?
Is my understanding correct?